# How can I sent the image with path from node js to python script

Tags: python, node.js

I want to send the path of the image to open and copy in the python script, then rename and send it back to node js, but when I send the path and use Image.open(open()) it not work

Node js

```
function filepath(file1, file2) { 
                    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
                    const python = spawn("python", ["test.py", file1, file2])

                    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                        var result = (data.toString())
                        console.log(result)
                    })
                    
                }
                filepath(req.files[0].path, req.files[1].path);
```

Python

```
import json
import sys
import shutil
from PIL import Image

filepath1 = sys.argv[1]
filepath2 = sys.argv[2]

Image.open(open(filepath1, 'rb'))

print(filepath1)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: if you want to communicate them, create server create  socket connection between then or at particular url commuincate

Comment: what does the console log show ? give us example of file1 and file2 names and what the console log prints and we will try to help, add the error stack that you are getting.... we can not help you with no info